# Get int value from command in c#

Tags: c#, sql

```
string sql = "Select UserId From User where UserName='Gheorghe'";


SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //this statement return 0
```

but I want to get the id of user?
how can I get it?

Comment: Make sure that your query returns at least one record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `SqlDataReader`.

> **SqlDataReader** Provides a way of reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database.

#### Sample

```
string sql = "Select UserId From User where UserName='Gheorghe'";

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
if (rd.HasRows) {
  rd.Read(); // read first row
  var userId = rd.GetInt32(0);
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - SqlDataReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Simply cast the returned value:

```
int userId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But be aware that **ExecuteScalar** will return **null** if your query returns an empty result set, and in that case the above code snippet will throw an [InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
try with select TOP 1 and ExecuteScalar

string sql = "Select TOP 1 UserId From User where UserName='Gheorghe'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
      var result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```