# How to save hit counter to database and retrieve it again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to make a hit counter for an MVC4 Project I'm working on that utilises the Razor syntax.

I've tried this following tutorial however I am looking for a solution that does not zero out the counter every time the solution gets restarted. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/46603/how-to-count-total-number-of-hit-in-Asp-Net-mvc.aspx

How do I save the value of hits into a database file and then retrieve it every time the solution loads?

I've implemented the above tutorial fully however I am looking for a solution that allows me to increase the counter every time the solution gets opened. (For example, it starts with 1 and the next time you open the solution, it would say 2 and so on)

I understand that you are meant to add a new table in the database etc however I'm stuck in terms of what to actually write. I've only ever used databases based on user input (ie from 'html forms', text boxes etc). I don't know how to make the whole process automated (in terms of saving/ editing/ loading the number). It's always been from user input and creating new views every time.

EDIT: I have a file in my `App_Data` folder of the solution named `MyMainDB.mdf`. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this refers to the database. When double clicked, it sends me to the Server Explorer and shows a file named `MyMainDBEntities`. Within this database, I have an existing table for a separate, irrelevant function, where I know I have to make a table. Once this table is made, what information does it require? Just an integer value named counter?

Here's an example of where I've used databases before:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PasswordSalt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { email=item.Email })
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { email = item.Email })
        </td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see, none of that is done automatically as the `ActionLink` at the bottom with the name `Edit` requires user input to click the button and then user input to assign a new value to the field.

Comment: Where are you at in the tutorial? Show the code that you have now, what doesn't work, and where you think the error may be.

Comment: @krillgar I've managed to implement the tutorial fully however is it not meant to increase every time the user refreshes the page?

Comment: So then find a tutorial on how to interact with a database in an MVC application. There are plenty of those out there. Every time you go through the Action methods, add one to what you have in the database and save it.

Comment: @krillgar I understand that you are meant to add a new table in the database etc however I'm stuck in terms of what to actually write. I've only ever used databases based on user input (ie from 'html forms', text boxes etc). I don't know how to make the whole process automated (in terms of saving/ editing/ loading the number). It's always been from user input so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you'll need to make 2 distinct changes from that of the tutorial you are following:

1)  You'll want to initialize the value from your database, instead of always starting from 0.

Per the tutorial:

*In Application_Start() method declare the variable like below code.*

```
var serviceLayer = new Services();
var initialCount = serviceLayer.GetCurrentCountFromDatabase();
Application["Totaluser"] = initialCount;
```

2) When you increment the count in the Session_Start method, you'll also want to increment it in the database.

Per the tutorial:

*Write the session_Start() method like below:*

```
protected void Session_Start()  
{  
      var serviceLayer = new Services();
      var count = (int)Application["Totaluser"] + 1;
      Application.Lock();
      serviceLayer.ExecuteQueryToUpdateCountInDatabase(count);
      Application["Totaluser"] = count;  
      Application.UnLock();  
}
```

This is assuming a class, 'Services' exists with implementations (c# sql queries - such as the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711605/get-int-value-from-command-in-c-sharp)) to extract this data from your database.

Comment: I have a file in my App_Data folder of the solution named `MyMainDB.mdf`. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this refers to the database. WHen double clicked, it sends me to the Server Explorer and shows a file named `MyMainDBEntities`. Within this database, I have an existing table for a separate, irrelevant function, where I know I have to make a table. Once this table is made, what information does it require? Just an integer value named counter?

Comment: You could, for example, create a table 'Metrics' with one column, 'TotalUsers' of type INT.  This would be all you need to be able to retrieve/update this value

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just one more question, where can I declare the functions for `"GetCurrentCountFromDatabase"` and `"ExecuteQueryToUpdateCountInDatabase"`? Below `Session_Start`? and would this not need a model too?

Comment: Ideally, yes, you would use a model - adding something like EntityFramework into your solution along with the model for this table would be the best solution.  However, for simplicity's sake, you could create a class, 'Services' in the project with implementations of the methods mentioned to extract the data.  I'll update the answer to support this approach.